# Angular mat-dialog undefined value afterClosed()

Tags: angular, typescript

i have been working in a project with angular 5 and angular material, i´m tryng to pass value to dialog and get the value back when the dialog is closed, but for some reason i´m getting undefined when the dialog is closed.

**Dialog**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReaderService } from '../../../../../services/reader/reader.service';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'fuse-comment-dialog',
  templateUrl: './comment-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class CommentDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  public commentsForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private readerService: ReaderService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CommentDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commentsForm = this.fb.group({
      commentText: ['', [
        Validators.required
      ]],
      commentType: 'PrivateComment',
      commentGroup: 'Therabytes'
    });
  }

  public sendComent(): void {
    this.data['text'] = this.commentsForm.value.commentText;
    this.data['commentVisibility'] = this.commentsForm.value.commentType;
    this.readerService.newComment(this.data)
      .then((commentId) => {
        this.data['id'] = commentId;
        this.dialogRef.close();
      });
  }

  public closeDialog(): void {
    this.commentsForm.value.commentText = '';
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

**Comment Component**

```
public commentDialog(): void {
    let newComment = {
      documentId: this.document.id
    };
    let commentDialogRef = this.dialog.open(CommentDialogComponent, {
      width: '300px',
      data: newComment
    });
    commentDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(comment => {
      console.log(comment);
      this.comments.push(comment);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to get the data from your modal to your `afterClosed()` Observable, you need to pass an argument to your `dialogRef.close()` method as follows:

```
this.dialogRef.close(this.data);
```

Comment: still  undefined for me  ,  in my case i have two lists with drag and drop components 
in the dialog , what should i do to return all data ?

Comment: @TheUnreal thank you. You saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

This issue had me stumped for a while.

Assuming that you've already tried the accepted answer and still have issues, please ensure that you inject `MatDialogRef`, instead of `DialogRef`.

Comment: Oh my god, this is exactly what I did...

Answer (score 0):

One reason why this could be happening is having both
`[mat-dialog-close]` and `(click)="dialogRef?.close()"` on the button to close the dialog, while only setting the data on one of them.